# How to make timer and alert in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make countdown timer in multiple choice. I want to display question one by one. But when I click next for the next question, the time is start from 10 minutes again, not continue.

How to make an alert if the time was over, it would be directly go to result?
 
Please help, I was beginner in javascript.

code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$randomizequestions ="yes";
$a = array(
1 => array(
   0 => "____ is a question that concerns the researchers who have been studying it.",
   1 => "Because the spotted owl’s survival",
   2 => "Whether the spotted owl can survive",
   3 => "Can the spotted owl’s survival",
   4 => "The spotted owl could survive",
   6 => 2
),
2 => array(
   0 => "Most shrubs should be fertilized early in the summer ____ late fertilizing can damage some plants.",
   1 => ". Only if",
   2 => "; in fact,",
   3 => ", which",
   4 => ": because",
   6 => 2
),
3 => array(
   0 => "In the eighth century, the calendar used in Europe was not as _____ used by the Mayans in Central America.",
   1 => "accurately as",
   2 => "accurate than",
   3 => "accurate as that",
   4 => "accurate that was",
   6 => 3
),
4 => array(
   0 => "_____ crude hydrocarbons into such products as gasoline and petrochemicals is at the heart of the petroleum industry.",
   1 => "Refine",
   2 => "Are refined",
   3 => "By refining",
   4 => "Refining",
   6 => 4
),
5 => array(
   0 => "We ____ visit Eric when we are in London.",
   1 => "ought  ",
   2 => "should  ",
   3 => "didn’t ought   ",
   4 => "ought to",
   6 => 2
),
6 => array(
   0 => "I hardly ever go swimming _______.",
   1 => "nowadays",
   2 => "soon",
   3 => "today",
   4 => "everydays",
   6 => 1
),
7 => array(
   0 => "Which word goes in the space? Can you look after the ___ rabbit while we are on holiday?",
   1 => "childrens’s  ",
   2 => "childrens’  ",
   3 => "children’s ",
   4 => "child",
   6 => 3
),
8 => array(
   0 => "The hummingbird’s agility in flight lets it ____ from flower to flower like an insect.",
   1 => "flit",
   2 => "flitting",
   3 => "to flit",
   4 => "flits",
   6 => 1
),
9 => array(
   0 => "We went to the cinema and we went out for a drink ___.",
   1 => "afterwards",
   2 => "after",
   3 => "then",
   4 => "and then",
   6 => 1

),
10 => array(
   0 => "Do ____ of you have any money I can borrow?",
   1 => "either  ",
   2 => "both  ",
   3 => "neither",
   4 => "Theres No Answer",
   6 => 1
),
11 => array(
   0 => "Justice Sandra Day O'connor was _____ to serve on the U.S Supreme Court.",
   1 => "the women who first",
   2 => "the first woman ",
   3 => "who the fisrt woman",
   4 => "the first and a woman",
   6 => 2
),
12 => array(
   0 => "North Carolina is well known not only for the Great Smoky Mountains National Park ____ for the Cherokee settlements",
   1 => "but also",
   2 => "also",
   3 => "because",
   4 => "because of",
   6 => 1
),
13 => array(
   0 => "Humans _____ by what holds objects together.",
   1 => "always fascinated",
   2 => "have always fascinated",
   3 => "always has been fascinated",
   4 => "have always been fascinated",
   6 => 4
),
14 => array(
   0 => "In eastern Canada _____ approaches two hundred inches in Quebec and Newfoundland.",
   1 => "where the seasonal rainfall",
   2 => "the seasonal rainfall",
   3 => "that the seasonal rainfall",
   4 => "the seasonal rainfall it",
   6 => 4
),
15 => array(
   0 => "Large, fast–moving trucks have been known to create blasts of wind _____ a motorcyclist.",
   1 => "can startle",
   2 => "can they startle",
   3 => "that can startle",
   4 => "are startling",
   6 => 3
),
);

$max=15;

$question=$_POST["question"] ;

if ($_POST["Randon"]==0){
        if($randomizequestions =="yes"){$randval = mt_rand(1,$max);}else{$randval=1;}
        $randval2 = $randval;
        }else{
        $randval=$_POST["Randon"];
        $randval2=$_POST["Randon"] + $question;
                if ($randval2>$max){
                $randval2=$randval2-$max;
                }
        }

$ok=$_POST["ok"] ;

if ($question==0){
        $question=0;
        $ok=0;
        $percentaje=0;
        }else{
        $percentaje= Round(100*$ok / $question);
        }

if ($persentaje == 100){
        $hasil="C2 Proficiency";
      }elseif ($persentaje > 80) {
        $hasil="C1 Advanced";
      }elseif ($persentaje > 60) {
        $hasil="B2 Upper Intermediate";
      }elseif ($persentaje > 50) {
        $hasil="B1 Intermediate";
      }elseif ($persentaje > 40) {
        $hasil="A2 Pre Intermediate";
      }elseif ($persentaje > 30) {
        $hasil="A2 Elementary";
      }else {
        $hasil="A1 Beginner";
      }    
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>TOEFL Online</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>

<script language='JavaScript'>
<!-- 
function Goahead (number){
        if (document.percentaje.response.value==0){
                if (number==<?php print $a[$randval2][6] ; ?>){
                        document.percentaje.response.value=1
                        document.percentaje.question.value++
                        document.percentaje.ok.value++
                }else{
                        document.percentaje.response.value=1
                        document.percentaje.question.value++
                }
        }
        if (number==<?php print $a[$randval2][6] ; ?>){
                document.question.response.value="Correct"
        }else{
                document.question.response.value="Incorrect"
        }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var detik = 3;
    var menit = 0;
    var jam = 1;
    function hitung() {
        setTimeout(hitung,1000);
        $('#tampilkan').html( + menit + ' Menit ' + detik + ' Detik ');
        detik --;
        if(detik < 0) {
            detik = 59;
            menit --;
            if(menit < 0) {
                menit = 9;
                jam --;
                if(jam < 0) {
                    jam = 0;
                    menit = 0;
                    detik = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    hitung();
});
// -->
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!--Start Header-->
<header class="page1">
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12">
      <h1><a href="#" onClick="goToByScroll('page1'); return false;"><img height="30px" width="1300px" src="images/logo2.png" alt=""></a></h1>
        <div class="menu_block">
        <nav class="">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li class="men1"><a onClick="goToByScroll('page1'); return false;" href="index.html">Home</a><strong class="hover"></strong></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--End Header-->

<div id="page2" class="content"> 
  <div class="container_12">\
  <div class="grid_14">
    <div class="box">
      <div id="tampilkan" class="slogan4" style="color:black; margin-left:150px; width:620px; padding:10px 0px; font-size:17px;">
      </div>
         <div style="background-color:#666666; color:white; margin-left:150px; width:620px; padding:10px 0px; font-size:17px;">? Test Your Level Of English Vocab/Grammar. 
          <div class="box3">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="5px" width="580px">
              <?php if ($question<$max){ ?>
              <tr><td>
                Tes ini tentang rammar dan vocabulary dan hasil dari tes ini akan membantu anda mengetahui level CEFR anda. Anda <b>tidak dapat melihat jawaban yang benar</b> pada tes ini. Anda harus menyelesaikan tes dalam 10 menit. Good Luck. <br><br>
                <hr>
              </td></tr>


              <tr><td>
              <form method="POST" name="question" action="">
              <br><strong><?php print $question+1; ?>. </strong><?php print "<b>".$a[$randval2][0]."</b>"; ?>
                <br><input type="radio" name="option" value="1"  onClick="Goahead (1);"><?php print $a[$randval2][1] ; ?>
                <br><input type="radio" name="option" value="2"  onClick="Goahead (2);"><?php print $a[$randval2][2] ; ?>
                <?php if ($a[$randval2][3]!=""){ ?>
                <br><input type="radio" name="option" value="3"  onClick="Goahead (3);"><?php print $a[$randval2][3] ; } ?>
                <?php if ($a[$randval2][4]!=""){ ?>
                <br><input type="radio" name="option" value="4"  onClick="Goahead (4);"><?php print $a[$randval2][4] ; } ?>

                <br><br>
              </form>
              <tr><td>
              <form method="POST" name="percentaje" action="<?php print $URL; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="response" value=0>
                <input type="hidden" name="question" value=<?php print $question; ?>>
                <input type="hidden" name="ok" value=<?php print $ok; ?>>
                <input type="hidden" name="Randon" value=<?php print $randval; ?>>
                <input style="font-family:Trebuchet ms; font-size:14.5px; width:80px; border:1px;" type="submit" value="Next">

              <br><br></form>
              </td></tr>
              <?php
              }else{
              ?>
              <tr><td align="center">
              The Quiz has finished<br>
              <br>Percentage of correct responses: <?php print $percentaje ; ?> %
              <br>Hasil: <?php print $hasil ?>
              <p><a href="<?php print $address; ?>">Restart</a>

              <?php } ?>

              </td></tr>

            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
      <div class="copy2"></a> &copy; Febriani F Damanik (132406106) | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> <br> </div>
</footer>


 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The timer would be done in JavaScript only, the PHP code you posted is almost entirely unrelated.   As for as the timer, `setTimeout` is the tool to use.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Maybe you couldn't see the Javascript needle in the PHP haystack, but he's using `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I saw it there, but I figure the OP cut-and-pasted code that he didn't orginally write, so I wanted to draw his focus to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using time counting on server side by PHP and sent it to JS on pageload. JS only display countdown, if time over let form.submit().

And you shouldn't send correct answer information on the source HTML like this, user can view-source and see correct answer.